# Adding numbers within a vector in r

Tags: r, vector, addition

I have a vector

```
v<-c(1,2,3)
```

I need add the numbers in the vector in the following fashion

```
1,1+2,1+2+3
```

producing a second vector

```
v1<-c(1,3,6)
```

This is probably quite simple...but I am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the cumulative sum function:

```
cumsum(v)
#[1] 1 3 6
```